# CPU info reported by lscpu inconsistent with AMD website

Tags: 64-bit, cpu

I have been setting up some old university computers and I need the CPU specifications.

But what is weird is that the result from `lscpu` and the info on the AMD website are different.

On the website, it says that AMD FX8350 is 8 cores, 8 threads.  However `lscpu` shows me that FX8350 does have 8 cores, but 2 threads/core => 16 in total!

What's more is that `lscpu` shows 4 cores per socket, but only one socket.

Does this means `lscpu` is not reliable or am I misunderstanding something?

**`lscpu` output**:

[image: lscpu output]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, `lscpu` is correct.  The screenshot states 2 threads per core, 4 cores per socket and 1 socket. 2 X 4 X 1 = 8 CPU(s).  I don't see how you get to 16.

AMD's claim the FX8350 is an "Eight-Core Processor" is controversial.  They describe it has having 8 *cores*, but only 4 *modules*.  For example, it only has 4 FPUs (floating point units), each shared by two threads.

The reddit user bridgmanAMD who works on linux drivers for AMD [states](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/5ipj0a/is_it_true_that_that_amd_fx_8350_8core_only_has_4/dba7j35/):

> IIRC the reason SW treats it as 4 cores with hyper-threading was because we asked to have it done that way - was the most practical way to get the OS to allocate threads optimally, ie spreading them across modules first and only putting two threads on a module after all four modules already had a first thread.

Comment: Thanks, that explains really well enough. Yeah, where confused me is that AMD claimed it's 8 cores processor, lscpu says it has 2 threads/core, so I came up with 16 hyper threads in total.